# Missing categories logs in iotHub monitoring

Tags: azure, monitoring, azure-iot-hub

I would like to follow cloud to device messages.

I used this page to enable operations monitoring :
[https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-operations-monitoring#a-namehow-to-enable-operations-monitoringacomment-activer-la-surveillance-des-opérations](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-operations-monitoring#a-namehow-to-enable-operations-monitoringacomment-activer-la-surveillance-des-op%C3%A9rations)

I switch "cloud-to-device communication" to Verbose.

I'm connected to associated EventHub but I have only logs for connection's category.

What's wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: "cloud-to-device communication" tracks **errors** such as [an unauthorized sender](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-operations-monitoring) and so on. Did you have such errors?

Comment: I want to log errors when thottling is reached. I make a load test where I'm sure to reach the number of cloud to device messages per second (with units number configured). And I want to watch this error somewhere. Have you got an idea ?

Answer (score 0):

For the "cloud-to-device communications" channel, the difference between the **Error** and **Verbose** settings is the amount of information included in each message. Only the "connections" channel changes the number of messages logged when you switch to the **Verbose** setting.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.